# UNC Path Injection Testing over NAT

Tags: penetration-test, nat, smb, virtualbox

I am penetration tester. I am struggling to check for UNC path injections in the web apps because of the environment that I am in. I am conducting a pentest of a web app in my company's local network. I am using a Windows 10 Host machine and a Kali VirtualBox Guest machine for testing.
Port forwarding capabilities are available in VirtualBox. As per my understanding, you cannot specify port when test UNC path injections because double backslashes would automatically resolve to SMB and not anywhere else. I have a Kali machine that has a NAT network configuration and does not have an independent IP. It cannot be put into bridged mode because the company policy does not allow assigning IP to a VM. I could turn off SMB service but I do not want to do this much work for this testing this single case.
My objective is to somehow forward the traffic that is coming on my windows host machine to my guest Kali VM.
P.S: I am local admin on my Windows machine.

Comment: This, then, is looking more like a pure Virtualbox networking question than a security question.

Comment: I would test UNC paths on the Windows box ...